# How to force a constraint to update in the Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I use AutoLayout to place my subviews within the superview. What I want from AutoLayout engine - is to calculate the width for the subview of `UIView` type and then in the same pass use this value for updating the position of this subview within its superview to make proper distribution of my subviews.
I use `NSLayoutConstraint`s type constraints for setting AutoLayout. My subview's width is equal to my view's height:

```
timer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (timer.widthAnchor)!, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

When I apply the set of constraints for a subviews, AutoLayout calculates theirs width and height based on padding for top and bottom constants.
That all stuff worked fine.When I tried to use subview's width for constraint's constants, that I expected to be calculated in one pass:

```
timer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: (self.view.bounds.width - 2*timer.bounds.width)/3)
```

I have got no luck here. I try to understand what is wrong and ended up with conclusion that on the moment when I apply my constraints and activate them the AutoLayout hasn't got updated value of subview's width. That become obvious when I try to:

```
print("timer.bounds.width", timer.bounds.width)
```

and got 0.0. I found similar questions here on the Stack and try to use

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
print("now timer's width is =", timer!.bounds.width)
```

Yes, now I got the timer width in the same pass, not "0", but the AutoLayout still doesn't use it.
The question is - how to force AutoLayout to use the updated value in the constraint constant.

Comment: `constant: (self.view.bounds.width - 2*timer.bounds.width)/3` Whoa. That's no way to form a constraint. You mustn't refer to the _bounds_ (or frame) of a view when forming a _constraint_! The entire notion makes no sense.

Comment: matt 's right, if you're going to use bounds or frames as a reference, use the NSLayoutDimension constraint methods instead. Also @matt , you got me off the ground with iOS with your iOS9 book series, big fan!!

Comment: @matt 'self.view.bounds.width' - refers to the superview(main view) bounds which contains 'timer' as a subview. Does using the value of the superview is forbidden? What I got, that constraint get only 'self.view.bounds.width' value  and 0 in 'timers.bounds.width.

Comment: @murphguy I have layout where I have to distribute 4 timer views with height=width (and i don't know the values) within the main view.  I use NSLayoutsDimension constraints to set padding from top and bottom of the screen(main view) to the timers and use same padding btwn timers vertically. AutoLayout calculates width=height for timers to fit the height of the screen. Now I have to distribute timers horizontally with equal spacing from the edges of screen and btwn timers also. Here I have to calculate the spacing btwn timers somehow. Or this distribution is possible to do without calculation?

Comment: "Now I have to distribute timers horizontally with equal spacing from the edges of screen and btwn timers also." Use spacer views, or UILayoutGuide spaces, or why not just let UIStackView do the work for you? That's what it's for, after all.

Comment: I think what Matt meant was that if you're going to use a frame reference in your constraint, you should tie that constraint to the frame, and pass constants to that constraint's method. However, since you're using the width, to (essentially) determine padding, you should set those variables somewhere outside of your constraint method. Like matt's answer bellow, if padding becomes very variable (can change between many different values), then you should just use a stackView or collectionView. Their flowlayout procotol handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution appeared to be simple - in the same pass just update constant value of my constraint that uses that width:

```
  MyTimer.constant = timer!.bounds.width
```

and than use AutoLayout engine to calculate the position of subview using updated constraint calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() again. It's not a great solution from a point of resources consumption. But for this particular case of my layout with uniform spacing it's pretty good one. What was not obvious that despite having reference on the variable in constant for the constraint I have to do it again.

Comment: Don't misuse the answer field for something that is not an answer. If you know the answer, just give it. If this is not the answer, but rather a further explanation of the question, edit the question.

Comment: Ok, I listened to your advice and edited both question and answer. I hope now it's more clear and concise.

Comment: Very much so! Removed my downvote. I have this comment: "What was not obvious that despite having reference on the variable in constant for the constraint I have to do it again" It _is_ obvious, actually. `timer!.bounds.width` is not some magic permanent connection with your `timer`; it's a _number_ whose value is obtained _right now_, whenever now is.  So maybe the problem here is that you don't understand what assignment is? Or what a value type is? Anyway, glad you got it sorted to your satisfaction.

Comment: Yes, you are right here, I doesn't understand an assignment here. I was convinced that if I place a 'CGFloat' value there like some number - it's will be a value, but not a reference, but when I place here some reference like timer!.bounds.width that would be updatable.

Comment: Excellent! You've perfectly understood your own mistake.